Using async with boxed error from a tokio::runtime
I got this piece of code that won't compile.
[dependencies] tokio = {version = "1.37.0", features = ["full"]} 
use std::error::Error;

async fn external_function() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>>{
  println!("This is an external function!");
  Ok(1)
}

async fn my_function(something: i32) {
  println!("This is my function {something}");
}

fn main() {
  println!("Hello, world!");
  let runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    runtime.spawn(async move {
      let v = external_function().await;
      if let Ok(x) = v {
          my_function(x).await;
      }
    });
}

The issue is that I got an async function from a crate that returns a Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
I want to process these results, and if it's Ok() call my function with the resulting value.
But I got this compiler error: error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
What would be the best practice to implement this without errors, given that I cannot modify the external_function()?
One solution would be to make my_function() non async, but what if I'd want that to be async as  well?

The external crate should be using Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>. But since you cannot change it, the simplest way is to take the error message and convert it to some other error type, e.g. io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err.to_string()).

Since you're ignoring the error anyway, the easiest solution is to change the Result to an Option before the next await point:
use std::error::Error;

async fn external_function() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("This is an external function!");
    Ok(1)
}

async fn my_function(something: i32) {
    println!("This is my function {something}");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    tokio::spawn (async move {
        let v = external_function().await;
        if let Some (x) = v.ok() {
            my_function (x).await;
        }
    });
}

Playground
Alternatively, you can use map_err to convert the Box<dyn Error> to some error type that implements Send, e.g.:
use std::error::Error;

async fn external_function() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("This is an external function!");
    Ok(1)
}

async fn my_function(something: i32) {
    println!("This is my function {something}");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    tokio::spawn (async move {
        let v = external_function().await;
        match v.map_err (|e| e.to_string()) {
            Ok (x) => my_function (x).await,
            Err (e) => println!("{e}"),
        }
    });
}

Playground

Thanks for the multiple solutions!
I get the second one. But what is the difference between changing the Result to Option instead to just handling only the Ok(x) of the result? Does changing the type here drop the Error part of the result entirely and that's why it doesn't fail for that case?

@VDave The difference is that when you leave the error as-is, the error is dropped at the end of the scope, and thus is saved in the future, making it non-Send. But if you use ok(), the error is dropped immediately, before the .await.


The issue is that I got an async function from a crate that returns a Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>

By returning Box<dyn Error>, that crate has given you an error type that is simply not at all guaranteed to be thread-safe. You cannot pass on this Box<dyn Error> except within single-threaded code.
Since the function is also async, that means its Future must also be run in a single-threaded environment, such as a LocalSet or simply calling Handle::block_on() from a new thread.
Once you've managed to run the future, in order to pass on the error through your own async functions, you are left with making use of what is provided by the Error trait:

Convert it to a string using the Display trait: call error.to_string().
Convert it to a string using the Debug trait: format!("{error:?}").
If you know the specific, concrete error type behind the dyn, and that type is Send, then you can use Error::downcast() to obtain that  type instead of dyn Error — then the lack of + Send on the dyn Error doesn't matter any more.


Thanks for the great theoretical explanation. I feel like I understand what it happens,  though it's still not clear why do I need to treat the error, since I mostly ignore it and if an error happens I just don't want my async function to run.
Shouldn't the if let Ok(x) =  v { just treat only the result?

@VDave Sorry, I misread your question and didn't realize you weren't propagating the error. That said, it's usually a bad idea to completely ignore errors — even if there's a known error you specifically need to ignore, some bug or misconfiguration might cause the operation to fail every time for a different reason, so you should at least store/log the error message somewhere that can be checked when troubleshooting is necessary.
